# Многомерный массив на РНР перевести в HTML-код меню с выпадающими списками

Tags: php

Есть многомерный массив на PHP, который хранит пункты меню в следующем виде:

```
$arr = [
    ['0-0','home','Home'],
    ['0-1','contacts','Contacts'],
    [
        '0-2',
        ['0-2-0','#!','Categories'], // кнопка меню, при клике по которой появляется выпадающий список
        ['0-2-1','category1','Category1'],
        ['0-2-2','category2','Category2']
    ]
];
```

Т.е. каждая кнопка меню являет собой массив. Если это простая обычная кнопка (без выпадающего списка), тогда это массив с трех элементов: айди пункта меню, путь/slug и название пункта меню. А если под кнопкой должен быть выпадающий список тогда это массив где сначала идет айди кнопки первого уровня, потом родительская кнопка, при клике по которой появляется выпадающий список (при чем она имеет свой айди), а потом пункты самого выпадающего списка.

Чтобы получить с массива на выходе HTML-код меню с выпадающим списком вида

```
<li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/contacts">Contacts</a></li>
<li><a href="/#!">Categories</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="/category1">Category1</a></li>
<li><a href="/category2">Category2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

обрабатываю массив следующим образом

```
$menuItems = [];
foreach($arr as $menuItem) {
    if(!is_array($menuItem[1])) { // если обычная кнопка меню
        $menuItems[] = '<li><a href="/'.$menuItem[1].'">'.$menuItem[2]."</a></li>\n";
    } else { // если кнопка меню с выпадающим списком
        $parentSlug = '/'.$menuItem[1][1]; // путь/слаг родительской кнопки
        $buttonAndSubmenu = '<li><a href="'.$parentSlug.'">'.$menuItem[1][2]."</a>\n";
        unset($menuItem[0],$menuItem[1]);
        $buttonAndSubmenu .= "<ul>\n";
        $submenu = [];
        foreach($menuItem as $submenuItem) {
            $parentSlug = str_replace('/#!','',$parentSlug);
            $submenu[] = '<li><a href="'.$parentSlug.'/'.$submenuItem[1].'">'.$submenuItem[2]."</a></li>\n";
        }

        $buttonAndSubmenu .= implode('',$submenu)."</ul>\n</li>";
        $menuItems[] = $buttonAndSubmenu;
    }
}
echo implode('',$menuItems);
```

Всё работает если кнопка меню первого уровня имеет выпадающий список второго уровня.

**Вопрос**: как быть если пункт выпадающего списка в свою очередь имеет свой выпадающий список т.е. если уровней вложенности может быть неизвестно сколько?

Например если вместо

```
...
['0-2-2','category2','Category2'],
...
```

будет

```
...
[
    '0-2-2',
    ['0-2-2-0','#!','Category2'],
    ['0-2-2-1','subcategory2-1','Subcategory2-1'],
    ['0-2-2-2','subcategory2-2','Subcategory2-2'],
],
...
```

Чувствую что нужна наверное какая то функция, которая бы работала "по кругу", но не могу додуматься как ее написать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Додумался все таки:

```
$menuItems = [];
foreach($arr as $menuItem) {
    if(!is_array($menuItem[1])) { // если обычная кнопка меню
        $menuItems[] = '<li><a href="/'.$menuItem[1].'">'.$menuItem[2]."</a></li>\n";
    } else { // если кнопка меню с выпадающим списком
        $menuItems[] = convert($menuItem);
    }
}
echo implode('',$menuItems);

function convert($menuItem) {
    $parentSlug = '/'.$menuItem[1][1]; // путь/слаг родительской кнопки
    $buttonAndSubmenu = '<li><a href="'.$parentSlug.'">'.$menuItem[1][2]."</a>\n";
    unset($menuItem[0],$menuItem[1]);
    $buttonAndSubmenu .= "<ul>\n";
    $submenu = [];
    foreach($menuItem as $submenuItem) {
        $parentSlug = str_replace('/#!','',$parentSlug);
        if(is_array($submenuItem[1])) {
            $submenu[] = convert($submenuItem);
        } else {
            $submenu[] = '<li><a href="'.$parentSlug.'/'.$submenuItem[1].'">'.$submenuItem[2]."</a></li>\n";
        }
    }
    $buttonAndSubmenu .= implode('',$submenu)."</ul>\n</li>";
    return $buttonAndSubmenu;
}
```